# Cannot get data from JSON of api in Kotlin

Tags: android, api, android-studio, kotlin

I have to use Kotlin for a project. Lets say I have some object called Note. I made the file in the following way

```
@Parcelize 
data class Notes (
val notes: List<Note>
): Parcelable

@Parcelize 
data class Note (
val id: Int,
val text: String
): Parcelable
```

I noticed that if the JSON returned is structured as follows and I also add @SerializedName("all_notes")

```
{
"all_notes": [
    {
       "id": 1,
       "text": "Some text"
    },
```

it works, but if the JSON returned is structured like this and i delete the @SerializedName notation

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "text": "Some text"
  },
```

i cant get the data.

I'm guessing I have to somehow use the serialized name but I'm not sure how to. I need to use the second type of JSON file. Can anyone help?

Edit: Someone gave the idea of posting the error I get so here it is

The error I get now is

> Error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was
>   BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

As I said before, it works when I use the other JSON file. It also works normally if I queue for just one object from the API and I say that Notes is just the variables from the Note. I get no error and I'd get that one Note printed out.

Comment: for your second json the return type should be directly `List<Note>`

Comment: Oh sorry, yea, I actually wrote it as List<Note> in my code. I will update the code above. Thank you.

Comment: From review: please provide if possible your `stacktrace` if there is a problem. Users will not be able to help if they don't know what's your problem. thanks

Comment: Okay, adding it right now. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for editing. the Error clearely state that your mapper expected an object of type `List` but your `json` contains and `array`. Please read my answer below: TL;DR you don't need your first class. you only need the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a problem with your `data` classes neither with your `json`. except that you don't need the first `data` class. You can map your json directly using your second class since your json will not respond with a list.

This is may be of a help to your. Use this [website](https://www.json2kotlin.com/) to construct a `kotlin` data class for your json responses.

You don't need to use `SerializedName` annotation unless your `data` class fields have a different name than your `json` attributes, because it's just a mapper hook used by `Gson` when mapping `json` into your class instance.

<s>Please clarify your problem more if the above didn't help you, we need to know what's is exactly your problem or `stacktrace` if you have any.</s>

Comment: I am very very thankful, I dont know how but that was the problem. 
I am using an interface to fetch data, and up until now i made it return Call<Notes>, but now that i changed it to Call<List<Note>> It works perfectly, thank you very very much